# I want to downgrade from net6.0 to net5.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-5, yolov8

I want to use YoloV8 in my C# Project. My Project uses Net5.0 version but the YoloV8 in Nuget Library use Netv6.0.
I've tried to change the TargetFramework Tag of the YoloV8 Library from net6.0 to net5.0 but it doesn't seem to work.
This is the Library i use: https://github.com/sstainba/Yolov8.Net/tree/main

What should I do to make the Yolov8 Library compatible with my project?

Thank you so much for helping me!!!

Comment: Why don't you **up**grade your codebase? Is there an older version of the lib that still provides the needed functionality _and_ is .Net 5 - compatible?

Comment: Actually my codebase is relied on many library, if i upgrade my codebase, it may be broken. There is no older version of the lib

Comment: _" if i upgrade my codebase, it may be broken."_ - So, you are planning to stay on .Net 5 no matter how out-of-date and unsupported by microsoft it becomes? Maybe reconsider that part. And the desired lib having no backports nor older versions only amplifies this urge.

Comment: It usually works just fine to use a library with a *lower* version, so updating your project is your best bet. If the library is open source you could create a fork and do whatever changes you want. But there is no easy way to change the version of a compiled assembly.

Comment: ^^ ... and to change it _downward_ at that. I'd really just give it a shot to move your code to .Net6. Just for a test. There's nothing to lose for you in doing that.

Comment: Also note that if you are on the .Net core branch you are basically committing to regular updates, since even LTS releases are only supported for 3 years.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, I really appreciate and consider your solutions

Comment: .NET 5 is out of support since May 10, 2022 - you should update your project, not downgrade the dependency.